# chapter 8 .micheal hartl ror 3rd edition

Tags: ruby-on-rails

hi i am presently on chapter 8 micheal hartl Learning Rails 3rd edition.
presently i am stucked in chapter 8 with above errors .I will highly appreciate if somebuddy help me out with it. Thanks in advance

when i run  bundle exec rake test it comes up with

```
sample_app git:(log-in-log-out) ✗ bundle exec rake test
Run options: --seed 16515

# Running:

......E............

Finished in 0.944425s, 20.1181 runs/s, 40.2361 assertions/s.

  1) Error:
SiteLayoutTest#test_layout_links:
NoMethodError: undefined method `full_title' for #<SiteLayoutTest:0x007ff8bea694b0>
    test/integration/site_layout_test.rb:12:in `block in <class:SiteLayoutTest>'

19 runs, 38 assertions, 0 failures, 1 errors, 0 skips
```

whereas my file posses the following

```
require 'test_helper'

class SiteLayoutTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  test "layout links" do
      get root_path
      assert_template 'static_pages/home'
      assert_select "a[href=?]", root_path, count: 2
      assert_select "a[href=?]", help_path
      assert_select "a[href=?]", about_path
      assert_select "a[href=?]", contact_path
      get signup_path
      assert_select "title", full_title("Sign up") 
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

`full_title` is a helper method defined in `application_helper.rb`. Check out https://www.railstutorial.org/book/_single-page#code-title_helper